# WCF доступ к клиентам

Tags: c#, .net, веб-программирование, asp.net, wcf

Есть WCF сервис развернутый на сервере, он имеет белый ip адрес. К нему подключаются клиенты, через интернет, у которых нет белого адреса. Вопрос, как я могу обратится с сервера к клиенту, если у него нет статического ip? Как мен известно у WCF есть дуплексное соединение, но работает ли оно с  не статическими ip адресами?

Answer (score 1):

В дуплексе:

TCP transport требует одно соединение между клиентом и сервером;

HTTP transport - здесь могут быть проблемы, потому что требуется два соединения: client -> server и server -> client;

Вывод: используйте TCP

Answer (score -1):

При необходимости принудительно передать информацию клиенту можно организовать на стороне WCF-сервиса флаг, который клиент будет периодически опрашивать. Изменением состояния этого флага служба WCF может сообщить клиенту, что ему нужно получить от службы определенную информацию.

Comment: Если таких разного рода данных много то флагов не напасешься. ;-)

Comment: Если таких данных много, то по аналогии, вместо булевого флага, можно использовать переменную int в которой передавать код того, что именно нужно запросить от WCF.

Comment: Это все костыли которые в итоге приведут к спагетти коду и не пониманию какой код за что отвечает. ;-)

Comment: Прямо сейчас столкнулся с той же проблемой, что описывает автор. Везде пишут, что поскольку WCF не поддерживается события  - рабочий вариант - callback (который я по сути и описал в своем ответе). Вот например http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739501/how-can-a-wcf-service-raise-events-to-its-clients). Так что спагетти, то спагетти, тут не поспоришь,  но выбора то другого пожалуй и нет.

Comment: Если вы так сильно привязаны к клиенту то WCF здесь не очень хорошо подходит, скорее вам нужен SignalR (WebSockets - bi-directional communication between the browser and server)